# How to render a React component inside of itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

I'm learning React and I'm trying to render the `<Comment/>` component inside of it self, however I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
Comment._this.getResponses
src/Comment.js:28
  25 |   );
  26 | }
  27 | getResponses = () => {
> 28 |   return this.props.responses.map(p => {
     | ^  29 |     return (
  30 |       <Comment
  31 |         author={p.author}
```

and the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Comment extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <a className="avatar">
          <img src={this.props.avatar} />
        </a>
        <div className="content">
          <a className="author">{this.props.author}</a>
          <div className="metadata">
            <span className="date">{this.props.timeStamp}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="text">
            <p>{this.props.text}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="actions">
            <a className="reply">Reply</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="comments">{this.getResponses()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  getResponses = () => {
    return this.props.responses.map(p => {
      return (
        <Comment
          author={p.author}
          avatar={p.avatar}
          timeStamp={p.timeStamp}
          text={p.text}
        />
      );
    });
  };
}

export default Comment;
```

Please note that `this.props.responses` is not `undefined`, and the problem only occurs while I'm trying to use the `Comment` component. If I replace the `Comment` component here:

```
return this.props.responses.map(p => {
  return <Comment
      author={p.author}
      avatar={p.avatar}
      timeStamp={p.timeStamp}
      text={p.text}
    />
});
```

with something like this:

```
return this.props.responses.map(p => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>author={p.author}</h1>
      <h1>avatar={p.avatar}</h1>
      <h1>timeStamp={p.timeStamp}</h1>
      <h1>text={p.text}</h1>
    </div>
  );
});
```

the code works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the rendering of `<Comment />` relies on the `responses` prop being defined.

Currently, when you render `Comment` components in `getResponses()`, there is no `responses` prop assigned to those comments:

```
<Comment
      author={p.author}
      avatar={p.avatar}
      timeStamp={p.timeStamp}
      text={p.text}
    />
```

This in turn means an error will be thrown when these `<Comment />` components are rendered, and they attempt to render "children" of their own (during the call to `getResponses()`) via the undefined `responses` prop.

To resolve this, you can check to see that the `this.props.responses` array is defined before proceeding to map and render `<Comment/>` components in the `getResponses()` method, like so:

```
getResponses = () => {

    // Check that responses prop is an array before
    // attempting to render child Comment components
    if(!Array.isArray(this.props.responses)) {
        return null;
    }

    return this.props.responses.map(p => {
      return (
        <Comment
          author={p.author}
          avatar={p.avatar}
          timeStamp={p.timeStamp}
          text={p.text}
        />
      );
    });
  };
```